# integrability condition stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the finite time interval $[0,T]$ and the stochastic process $(X(t); t\leq s)$ Can the integral 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}X(s)ds
\end{align}
de defined if the stochastic process $X$ is not bounded on $[0,T]$ ?

Comment: In general: No. Any further assumptions on $X$ (e.g. cadlag/caglad/...)?

Comment: Thank you, i agree. It is  cadlag process, which moreover is square integrable in the mean  \begin{align}\mathbb{E}\int_{0}^{T}X^{2}(s)ds < \infty   \end{align}

Comment: Note that cadlag processes are bounded on compact (time)intervals.

Comment: you mean locally ?

Comment: For each fixed $\omega$ and $T>0$, there exists $M=M(\omega,T)$ such that $|X(t,\omega)| \leq M$ for all $t \leq T$.

Comment: nice, thank you much!